# Javascript, regular expression and link

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this part of code

```
<a href='project.php?id=5'>test</a>
```

Where `id` number can have different length and I need to extract only this number.
Is it possible through regular expression, or something better?

**EDIT**

I prob have solution, fitting my problem, what you think about:

```
string.split('=')[2].split('\'')[0]
```

When string contains text. I'm sure, that text will always have same pattern

Comment: This is part of your document or is it inside a string?

Comment: Other than using regular expressions, is there a reason why you are not using ``data``-attributes? It would make your life a bit easier, and your javascript code much cleaner.

Comment: @Kippie Using `data-` attributes like this is a horrible broken approach that disregards separation of concerns and how applications should be structured. The ID of the project has nothing to do with the presentation, storing your data on the DOM instead of in JavaScript is a blatent disregard of how an application should be structured. You need to aspire to a single source of truth in your application. Storing data in the DOM instead of in JS objects (like any sensible design in any UI ever does) is a recipe for code spaghetti.

Comment: This is inside string

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Could you elaborate on this? How does this go against SoC? Why **would** it have to do anything with presentation? I understand your point about single source of truth (id being specified in both the ``href``- as well as the ``data``-attribute). However, your point of storing data in the DOM instead of in JS objects is still unclear to me.

Comment: @Kippie I'd like to avoid chat in the comments here, I'm often in the JavaScript chat room here in StackOverflow, you can ping me there

Comment: @LubošSuk About your solution - it fails for: `<a style='color:red' href='project.php?id=5'>test</a>` or `<a href="project.php?id=1">test</a>` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you have your string `"<a href='project.php?id=5'>test</a>"`

<sup>Using regular expressions to parse HTML can get real ugly real fast (what if the `a` has more attributes? What if there are multiple tags there?)</sup>

The cleanest would be to dump it in a new HTML element and process it as HTML using the powerful native built in DOM API instead of as a string.

```
var temp = document.createElement("div");
temp.innerHTML = "<a href='project.php?id=5'>test</a>";
var url = temp.firstChild.href; // now contains project.php?id=5
```

Now we can use more traditional tools to extract the id

```
var id = url.split("=")[1]; // the first thing after =.
```

More generally the strategy is:

- Create an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) or a [fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment) and put our HTML there
- Use DOM querying methods to find our elements, in this case `.firstChild` was enough but [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) or even [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) might be useful.
- Once we got the attribute, it's just a simple string, and we can safely use regex for it, or any other string processing method we choose.

If you're unacquainted with the DOM API [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_Reference/Introduction) is a good place to start. It's how we process the document with JavaScript and knowing it is important to your success as a front end JavaScript developer.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3J2n/)

Comment: Its interesting, but i really parse string, not html element. And not sure if it will have some problems with performance, make this an element.

Comment: `"<a href='project.php?id=5'>test</a>"` __is__ representing HTML. The performance of this solution should not concern you unless you're doing tens of millions of these extractions every second.

Comment: @LubošSuk Getting the correct result is more important then performance. Also, don't worry about performance until it becomes a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parse(url){
    var result = { pathname: null, search: {} };
    var parts = url.split('?');
    result.pathname = parts[0];
    var search = parts[1];
    if(search){
        var ps = search.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < ps.length; i++){
            var p = ps[i].split('=');
            result.search[p[0]] = p[1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

parse('project.php?id=5');
```

**EDIT**: To get anchor element:

```
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
 for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++){
     var a = anchors[i];
     if(a.innerHTML === 'test')
         console.log(parse(a.href));
 }
```

Comment: I don't think OP's problem is getting the ID from the link href itself, rather it's to extract the link from the HTML.